# UIButton displaying a triangle

Tags: objective-c

I have a UIButton and i want it to display a triangle. Is there a function to make it a triangle? Since im not using a UIView class im not sure how to make my frame a triangle.

```
ViewController(m):

- (IBAction)makeTriangle:(id)sender {
UIView *triangle=[[UIView alloc] init];
triangle.frame= CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
triangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view addSubview: triangle];
```

Do i have to change my layer or add points and connect them to make a triangle with CGRect?
If im being unclear or not specific add a comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A button is a subclass of UIView, so you can make it any shape you want using a CAShape layer. For the code below, I added a 100 x 100 point button in the storyboard, and changed its class to RDButton.

```
@interface RDButton ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIBezierPath *shape;
@end

@implementation RDButton

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 0, 0, 0); // move the title down to make it look more centered
        self.shape = [UIBezierPath new];
        [self.shape moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0,100)];
        [self.shape addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100,100)];
        [self.shape addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(50,0)];
        [self.shape closePath];
        CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        shapeLayer.path = self.shape.CGPath;
        shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2;

        [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self.shape containsPoint:[touches.anyObject locationInView:self]])
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

The touchesBegan:withEvent: override restricts the action of the button to touches within the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

A view's `frame` is always a rect, which is a rectangle. Even if you apply a transform to it so it no longer looks like a rectangle, the `view.frame` property will still be a rectangle -- just the smallest possible rectangle that contains the new shape you have produced.

So if you want your UIButton to look like a triangle, the simplest solution is probably to set its type to `UIButtonTypeCustom` and then to set its image to be a png which shows a triangle and is transparent outside of the triangle.

Then the UIButton itself will actually be rectangle, but will look like a triangle.

If you want to get fancy, you can also customize touch delivery so that touches on the transparent part of the PNG are not recognized (as I believe they would be by default), but that might be a bit trickier.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean "set its image to be a png which shows a triangle and si transparent outside of the triangle"

Comment: I mean, create a PNG which is completely transparent except for an opaque triangle that covers part of its area. Then do `[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"triange.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`